# How to access Tomcat Manager without authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to access manager from localhost without authentication to pull some information about server status (docker healtcheck). At the same time I want to access it from remote address to pull information from jmxproxy (splunk agreagation) BUT with authentication. I can not even access manager without password from localhost, always asking for credentials.
I am using Tomcat 8.5.

Is it possible?
Thanks

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html